# creating a badge in the navbar and getting data from controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I'm using `laravel`. I'm trying to create a badge in the `navbar` and getting the number of rows from a specific table in the database. I have the following codes for the `navbar`:

```
<span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>
    @php !empty(session('notifications.all2')) ? print(array_sum(session('notifications.all2'))) : "" 
    @endphp
</span>
```

and this for the controller:

```
class NotificationsController extends Controller
{
    public function index ()
    {
        $settings = NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->get();

        $user = User::where('id', auth::id())
            ->select('id')
            ->first();


        if(count($settings) == 0)
        {
            $tasks = Tasks::all();
            foreach ($tasks as $task)
            {
                NotificationSettings::create([
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'name' => $task->name,
                    'module' => 'Task Schedule'
                ]);

                $settings = NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->get();
            }
        }

        $checkRestockTask = Tasks::where('name', 'Available Restock Inventory')->first();

        if($checkRestockTask){
            $checkUser = NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->where('name', 'Available Restock Inventory')
                        ->first();
            if(!$checkUser){
                NotificationSettings::create([
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'name' => 'Available Restock Inventory',
                        'module' => 'Task Schedule'
                    ]);

                $settings = NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->get();
            }
        }
        
        $data = [
            'active' => 'settings',
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'role' => $user->role_id ? $user->role_id : 'null',
            'tasks' => $settings
        ]; //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";
        
        return view('notifications.index2')->with($data);
    }

    public function add ()
    {
        $data = array(
            'active' => 'settings',
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        ); //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>"; die();
        return view('notifications.add')
            ->with($data);
    }

    public function saveNotification (Request $request)
    {
        $module = $request->get('module');
        $user_id = $request->get('user_id');
        $notification_name = $request->get('notification_name');

        if($module == 1)
        {
            $module_name = 'Task Schedule';
        }

        $saved_notifs = NotificationSettings::where('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->select('name')
                        ->get();

        $notif_names = array();

        foreach ($saved_notifs as $saved_notif)
        {
            array_push($notif_names, $saved_notif->name);
        }
            
        if(in_array($notification_name, $notif_names))
        {
            return back()->with('error', 'Notification already added');
        }
        else
        {
            NotificationSettings::create([
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'name' => $notification_name,
                'module' => $module_name
            ]);

            return redirect('notifications');
        }
    }

    public function editNotification (Request $request, $user_id = null)
    {
        $checked_tasks = explode(',', $request->get('tasks'));

        if(count($checked_tasks) > 0)
        {  
            NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                            ->whereIn('name', $checked_tasks)
                            ->update(['status' => 1]);

            NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                            ->whereNotIn('name', $checked_tasks)
                            ->update(['status' => 0]);
        }
        else
        { 
            NotificationSettings::where('user_id', $user_id)
                            ->update(['status' => 0]);
        }

        $settings = NotificationSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->get();

        return json_encode($settings);
    }

    public function getTasks ()
    {
        $tasks = Tasks::select('name', 'id')
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->get();

        $data = array(
            'tasks' => $tasks,
        ); //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>"; die();
        
        return $data;
    }

    public function viewAllNotifications ()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        
        $view = Notification::where('recipient_id', $user_id)
            ->where('viewed', 0)
            ->update(['viewed' => 1]);

        $notifications = Notification::where('recipient_id', $user_id)
                    ->join('stores', 'stores.id', '=', 'notifications.store_id')
                    ->select('notifications.content', 'notifications.recipient_id', 'notifications.url', 'notifications.read', 'notifications.viewed', 'stores.name', 'notifications.created_at', 'notifications.updated_at')
                    ->orderBy('notifications.id', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(25);

        $data = array(
            'active' => 'settings',
            'notifications' => $notifications,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
        );
      
        // return $data;
        return view('notifications.all2')
            ->with($data);
    }

    public function getAllNotifications(Request $request){
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        
        $view = Notification::where('recipient_id', $user_id)
            ->where('viewed', 0)
            ->update(['viewed' => 1]);

        $notifications = Notification::where('recipient_id', $user_id)
                    ->join('stores', 'stores.id', '=', 'notifications.store_id')
                    ->select('notifications.content', 'notifications.recipient_id', 'notifications.url', 'notifications.read', 'notifications.viewed', 'stores.name', 'notifications.created_at', 'notifications.updated_at')
                    ->orderBy('notifications.id', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(25);

        return json_encode($notifications);
    }
}
```

I just cant seem to get the number appear in the badge/pill that i have created. thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: you just forget to put the value to the session e.g: `session(['notification.all2' => $data]);`

Comment: oh cool. let me try that. thanks!